# Java NIO Exception

Tags: java, iterator, nio, socketchannel

Hi I am trying to make a chat using NIO, in the server part in a separate thread from the main when I :

```
private void broadcast(String msg, String user)    
{
    String Message = user + ":" + msg + "\0";
    System.out.println(Message);
    ByteBuffer buf=ByteBuffer.wrap(Message.getBytes());
    Set<SelectionKey> selectedKeys  = selector.keys();
    Iterator<SelectionKey> keyIterator = selectedKeys.iterator();

    while(keyIterator.hasNext()) 
    {
        SelectionKey key = keyIterator.next();
        if(key.attachment() != user)
        {
            try {
                ((SocketChannel) key.channel()).write(buf);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            buf.rewind();
        }
        keyIterator.remove();
    }
}
```

I get this exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.remove(Unknown Source)
at chatserver.MessageSender.broadcast(MessageSender.java:41)
at chatserver.MessageSender.run(MessageSender.java:113)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Line 41 is: keyIterator.remove();
I am using this as guideline: [Java NIO Tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/index.html)

Comment: What does the exception have to do with the title? What don't you understand about the exception?

Comment: As mentioned you can not remove from collection while iterating. The exception is not related to NIO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are invoking `Selector.keys()` where you appear to want `Selector.selectedKeys()`.  The `Set` returned by the former is documented to be completely unmodifiable, whereas the one returned by the latter -- which agrees better with the name of the variable to which you assign the result -- is documented to permit element removal.  Moreover, the selected keys are the ones ready for I/O.

Comment: actually no, I need Selector.keys() since I need to get all the channels and send them the message from 1 user. In a very strange manner this exception stopped appearing after doing nothing special.

Comment: @Phoenix In that case you shouldn't be calling `remove()` at all. If you want to remove a key from the registered-key set, cancel it. But you probably don't want to do that either, You call `remove()` when iterating the selected-key set because otherwise it isn't removed and gets processed again next time. That logic doesn't apply to the registered-key set.

Comment: Eh? A channel must be in non-blocking mode to be registered with a Selector.